# postgres insert into same id

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have this table1:

| product | amount | timestamp_local |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prdct_1 | 100 | 2022-03-15 |
| Prdct_2 | 50 |  |
| Prdct_3 | 40 | 2023-05-05 |

I want to insert into this table2

| product | amount | timestamp_local |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prdct_1 | 100 |  |
| Prdct_2 | 50 | 2021-12-30 |
| Prdct_3 | 40 |  |

This is my query but it doesn't work.

```
insert into table2 (timestamp_local)
select timestamp_local from table1 b
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where id = b.id);
```

How could I solve it? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hint : **upsert operation**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT INTO table2 (product, amount, timestamp)
SELECT
product,
amount,
COALESCE(timestamp, '2021-12-30') AS timestamp
FROM table1;

Comment: please always explain in Detail what your approach is.

Answer (score 1):

You can Do a so called UPSERT.

```
insert into table2 (id,product,     amount,     timestamp_local)
select id, product,     amount,
CASE WHEN   timestamp_local IS NULL  then
'2021-12-30' ELSE NULL END timestamp_local 
from table1 b
ON CONFLICT(id) DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that certain important components are missing from your query, including the product and amount columns from the INSERT and SELECT clauses.
In order to add entries from table 1 to table 2, you can try the following query, which pulls entries from Table 1 and inserts them into Table 2 only in the case that Table 2 does not have a matching  product and amount combination.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (product, amount, timestamp)
SELECT product, amount, timestamp
FROM table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 b
    WHERE a.product = b.product AND a.amount = b.amount
);
```

Hope it's helpful :)